# Telethon give an error when scrap group more than 6K member ('ChannelParticipants' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Telethon give an error when scrap group more than 6K member ('ChannelParticipants' object is not subscriptable)

```
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=False)
```

I also set aggressive=False, but when I scrap group more than 6k members, it gives me an error.

so is there any way to set a limit on member scrap on Big group so it will only scrap 5k to 6k member and it saves after scrap 5k member and does not receive the error

Answer (score 0):

you can use limit parameter in

```
client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=False,limit=4000)
```

it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).